# Is the lvalue-to-rvalue conversion applied during the initialization of scalar types

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

The question is exactly what the title states. [[dcl.init] p17.9](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init#17.9) is the only place I found that specifies how object of scalar types are to be initalized, however it places no restrictions onto the value category of the initalizer. Is it a similar situation to how the value category of the right operand for assignment is not specified, but we infer it to be a prvalue?